# отображение картинки (текстуры) LWJGL java

Tags: java, button, lwjgl

Возможно совсем примитивный и заезжанный вопрос, но как отобразить картинку (текстуру картинки) в окне с помощью lwjgl. Хотел создать свои кастыли кнопок, т.к. по понятным причиным в opengl их нет. Место квадратиков хочу использовать полноценные текстуры кнопок, но не знаю как создать и поместить текстуру на поле. Долго пытался гуглить, но везде либо предлагают кастыли или библеотеки или пишут про с/с++. Искренне надеюсь на помощь от вас и надеюсь меня не пошлют в гугл)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для начала надо развертывать текстуру на 2д плоскость и вырезаем из нее части, которые позже можно передать 3д координаты, для текстурирования моделей.

```
 ModelTexture texture = model.getTexture();
    shader.loadShineVariables(texture.getShineDamper(), texture.getReflectivity());

GL13.glActiveTexture(GL13.GL_TEXTURE0);
GL11.glBindTexture(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, model.getTexture().getID());
```